# VBA check each row in a particular column

Tags: excel, vba

I want to check each row in column `F` whether is there any value inside. Most of it are empty, however, if there is any characters inside, I need to check if the first character of the string is `A`, `B` or `C` which than actions will be taken depending on the first character. How can i execute this? Currently I only found some resources code like this which isnt really helpful to what I'm doing. Also for looping thru each row to check, im using this code

```
While Cells(8 + i, 1).Value <> ""

        i = i + 1
Wend
```

and for getting the first character of a string i found

```
Sub FirstChar()
    Dim xlString As String
    Dim xlFirstChar As String

    xlString = "01999102477490"

    xlFirstChar = Left$(xlString, 1)

    MsgBox xlFirstChar
End Sub
```

But this only checks 1 cell....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Sub CheckFirstChar()
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    ' Find last cell in column F
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lastRow
        firstChar = Left(Cells(i, 6).Value, 1)
        If firstChar = "A" Or firstChar = "B" Or firstChar = "C" Then
            ' Take some actions
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: A `Select Case` might be useful instead of multiple `If` statements in this case.